# Use the current date inside the repeatable() statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently building a stored procedure that we'll be running once per day to sample data and look for anomalies. If anomalies are found I want the sample to be repeatable so I can perform deeper analysis.

To do this I'm using a `tablesample() repeatable()` statement:

```
select * 
from DataTable tablesample(50 rows) repeatable(cast(getdate() as int));
```

This gives the error:

> Invalid ROWS value or REPEATABLE seed in the TABLESAMPLE clause for table "DataTable". The value or seed must be an integer.

I've also tried using `convert(int, getdate())` instead, to no avail. I've also confirmed that using a plain integer literal inside the statement works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a variable or an expression there.  Only a integer literal.  You can always use dynamic SQL.  eg

```
declare @seed int = cast(getdate() as int)
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('SELECT * FROM Person.Person TABLESAMPLE (10 PERCENT) REPEATABLE (',@seed,');')

exec (@sql)
```